# Printing word by word from a sentence

Tags: c++, string, split

I have a sentence "Computer Science" as my input and I want to print Computer and Science seperately. I wrote a program in c++ but it is printing only "Computer". Could anyone help me find out why it is not printing both the words seperately?

```
int main()
{
    char string[]="Computer Science";
    int l;
    l=strlen(string);
    char begin[l];
    int i=0,ind=0;

        while(string[i]!='\0')
        {
            begin[ind]=string[i];
            if(string[i]==' ')
                {
                    begin[ind]=NULL;
                    cout<<begin<<"\n";

                    ind=0;
                    //ind++;
                    i++;
                }
            else
            {

                ind++;
                i++;
            }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only print when you encounter a space character in the input. There's no space after `Science`

Comment: @user4532954  Now write a program that prints only "Science". Then combine the two programs in one program.:)

Comment: Why don't you use C++, i.e. `std::string` and `std::istringstream` to do this?

Comment: you can change your condition to `if(string[i] == ' ' || i == l)`. I think this will work pretty well with std::string s

Comment: I don't understand why, if you increment `i` in both sides of the `if` statement at the end, why not only put a single `i++;` statement _after_ the complete `if` statement instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking only for space which printing output. Science has null after it not space.
Change while to

```
while(i <= l)
```

Change your if condition to

```
if(string[i]==' ' || string[i] == '\0')
```

Comment: Oh... yes its not going inside while loop while string[i] is null. Updated

Comment: @ShashwatKumar [Still doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38696e7a1113d1c5)!

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Huh??

Comment: @ShashwatKumar R** **re! Better improve your answer.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar I've got a compilation error from exactly replicating your proposed changes to the OP's original code, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Modern C++ offers a lot of features for handling strings. These features are designed to simplify handling string in more efficient way. Don't use C-Style string unless you have to. In your case, you could do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str("Computer Science");
    for(int i(0); i < str.size(); ++i){
        if( str[i] == ' ' )
            std::cout << '\n';
        else{
            std::cout << str[i];
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

With C++, you can do more reduction but I leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Variable Length Arrays (VLA) is not a standard feature of C++. Moreover there is no need to declare one more array that to output words separated by spaces.

Your program never outputs the second (or last) word in the string if there are no spaces after it.

And the program includes leading spaces in words because it does not skip spaces when there are more than one space between words.

The program can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    char s[] = "Computer Science";

    for ( const char *p = s; *p != '\0'; )
    {
        while ( *p == ' ' || *p == '\t' ) ++p;

        if ( *p )
        {
            size_t i = 0;

            while ( *p and not ( *p == ' ' || *p == '\t' ) )
            {
                ++i;
                ++p;
            }

            std::cout.write( p - i, i ) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Computer
Science
```

For the condition

```
*p == ' ' || *p == '\t'
```

you could use a lambda expression. For example

```
auto is_blank = []( char c ) { return c == ' ' || c == '\t'; }
```

and then in loops you could write for example

```
while ( is_blank( *p ) ) ++p;
```

and

```
while ( *p and not is_blank( *p ) )
```

Or you could use standard C function `isspace` declared in header `<cstring>` to check the condition.

The task can be done using standard algorithms and iterators. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    char s[] = "Computer Science";

    std::istringstream is( s );

    std::copy( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( is ),
               std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
               std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( std::cout, "\n") );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as above that is

```
Computer
Science
```